# Overflow: hidden - scrolling

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to use `overflow: hidden` in body section in CSS while still making possible to scroll using arrows on keyboard?

Also, I'd love to use "drag" option to navigate (scroll) in my div. Is it possible? Just like in Google Maps

Answer (score 0):

You could try `overflow:scroll;` this should allow you to scroll to see the overflow.

Comment: But the scrolling bar will be still visible. I dont want it.

Comment: @Kajcioch You may want to add that to your question along with what you tried to solve the problem (research/attempts).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `overflow:scroll;`, or can be more specific like, `overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll`. But this will show the scroll bar (You can have a look into `::-webkit-scrollbar`, to modify the scrollbar, but I believe any changes will be global).

Also, Google Maps achieve the functionality using javascript. I am not aware of any technique to implement a similar functionality using just HTML and CSS. If you find out, kindly post your approach.